# Accept fails on invalid argument, followed by bad file descriptor

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking, tcp

We have a server that has been perfectly functional for the past few months. However, out of the blue - yesterday - the server failed to accept a connection with "invalid argument", and subsequently with "bad file descriptor".

Every site/suggestion I've checked says I should have a `listen()` after `bind()` and before `accept()`. I do, and I'm also checking for errors on `listen()`.

I am correctly passing the size of the client `sockaddr_in`, to `accept()`, and it is initialised to the size of the client sockaddr_in variable.

I have also checked to make sure I am using `AF_INET` along with `sockaddr_in` (as opposed to `AF_UNIX` or `sockaddr_un`.

Any ideas?

Basic pseudocode:

```
struct sockaddr_in server;
struct sockaddr_in client;
socklen_t client_size;

if ((mysock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) exit;

memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));
// Set socket options
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
server.sin_port = 8000;

if (bind(mysock, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server)) < 0) exit;

if (listen(mysock, 100) < 0) exit;

while (1)
{
    clientsock = accept(mysock, (struct sockaddr *) &client, &client_size);
    if (clientsock == -1)
        printf("Accept failed() - %s\n", strerr(errno));
    else
        //do server stuff here
}
```

It was working fine one minute, and the next it started printing a ton of "Accept failed()" errors, the first one being `Invalid Argument` and the rest were `Bad file descriptor`.

Nothing changed on that server (that we know of).

Note: clientsock and mysock are initialised. I just have not shown it here. If you see issues with parentheses, it's a copy-paste issue, not a code issue. Like I said, the server has been fine for a long time.

Comment: You can't have `8000` as port number, it should be in network byte order (which might be the same as your host byte order, but if you're on a normal PC then you need to use the `htons` function). Also, don't you mean `SOCK_STREAM`?

Comment: And regarding your error, you might want to read about [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: "*If you see issues with parentheses, it's a copy-paste issue, not a code issue.*" copypasting wouldn't change levels or oders or parenthesis. Always show "real" code please, we are not here to chase typos or such. Thank you!

Comment: @alk I realise I should paste real code as often as possible. Sometimes this is not possible, as in this case.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I've corrected the parentheses regarding operator precedence, and yes SOCK_STREAM.

Comment: "*the first one being Invalid Argument and the rest were Bad file descriptor.*" could it be you are (accidently) closing one of the file descriptor `0`, `1` or `2` somewhere in the code. How are you initialising/marking invalid socket descriptors? This typically is done before usage or after having `close()`ed them? Add the file descriptor's value to the error message issued in case a socket operation (here: `accept()`) fails.

Comment: @alk I looked for all calls to closing the server listening socket. There are none. Also, no closing 0,1 or 2 anywhere. After closing the clientsock, I change the value to -1. I'll add the fd value to the printout, but that will have to wait for a release.

Answer (score 2):

As the `<`-operator binds tighter then the `=`-operator this

```
if (mysock = socket(AF_INET, SOCKSTREAM, 0) < 0) exit;
```

shall look like this

```
if ((mysock = socket(AF_INET, SOCKSTREAM, 0)) < 0) 
  exit;
```

or even better (as more obvious and though more safe) like this:

```
mysock = socket(AF_INET, SOCKSTREAM, 0);
if (0 > mysock)
{
  exit;
}
```

Comment: I shall change that. However, why would this server have run for months without any issues, and suddenly start this. We killed it and restarted it, and it has been functioning normally ever since.

Comment: Also, that's actually a typo in my question. The actual code has the brackets set in your first suggestion.

Comment: I've added a +1 because the parentheses issue was a typo on my part.

Comment: @Sagar: You want to say it ran without errors, then showed the errors as per your question, then you did a restart and since then it is running again without errors?

Comment: exactly! That's what is confusing me. It was running fine, when suddenly we started seeing a whole bunch of bad file descriptor errors. We had to do a kill -9 and restart the server, and it has been running normally ever since.

Comment: "*... had to do a kill -9*" are "normal" shutdown did not work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60030/discussion-between-alk-and-sagar).